# export XTS to CSV, with separate columns

Tags: r, csv, time-series, xts, zoo

I currently have some time series data and it is in XTS form. This is some of it below.

```
head(dbt)
                    NSW1.Price     Coal
2018-01-01 00:30:00      91.86 71.29267
2018-01-01 01:00:00      88.83 71.25520
2018-01-01 01:30:00      73.62 71.22649
2018-01-01 02:00:00      71.49 71.18284
2018-01-01 02:30:00      69.27 71.14081
2018-01-01 03:00:00      68.44 71.10430
```

I am trying to export this to a CSV file, but when I do, it doesn't export into separate columns. This is what happens when I try export it.

[image: current csv output]

The code I am using is

```
write.zoo(dbt,file="export.csv",index.name="okay",row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `sep=","`.

Directly from the help for `write.zoo`:

```
read.zoo and write.zoo are convenience functions for reading and writing "zoo"
series from/to text files. They are convenience interfaces to read.table and
write.table, respectively.


... further arguments passed to read.table, write.table, or read.zoo, respectively.
```

Hence, this should work:

```
write.zoo(dbt,file="export.csv",index.name="okay",row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,sep=",")
```